# How to access MySQL database in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I am new to WordPress. I have a custom form through which I am sending emails. I want to save the email data into one of my databases.

The database is not listed inside the WP i.e. I have created another `DB`.

```
define( 'DB_NAME', 'i3105069_wp2' );

/** MySQL database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'root' );

/** MySQL database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', '' );

/** MySQL hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
```

The above is my `wp-config` file. I have already created a new database and tables in my `phpMyAdmin`.

**Following is the list of databases:**

[image: List of DBs]

In the above picture, the red mark DB is the one which I want to add and the green marked is the one that is already added.

**Update 1**

I tried to do the following. Adding the new configurations inside my `wp-config` file and trying to access a table from one of my forms.

```
$mydb = new wpdb('username','password','database','localhost');
$rows = $mydb->get_results("select Name from my_table");
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($rows as $obj) :
  echo "<li>".$obj->Name."</li>";
 endforeach;
echo "</ul>";
```

But I am getting `This page isn’t working HTTP 500`

How I can access any DB outside WordPress?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to access a database other than the WordPress database inside WordPress? Did you create a theme or a plugin?

Comment: yes I want to access database other than WordPress. Create a theme

Answer (score 0):

You can use the global $wpdb for this as you have posted.

```
$mydb = new wpdb('username','userpassword','accountant_quotes','localhost');
```

which works 100%. You can open any number of databases within your site this way.

**The error 500 could simply be your username/pword combo is wrong, so $mydb is returned as null. Therefore get_results will cause a 500 error. You wp-config indicates a username of 'root' with no password : bad idea btw**.

Comment: `$mydb = new wpdb('username','userpassword','accountant_quotes','localhost');` its working on my main page. But at the page where I actually wants to do something to DB i.e. inserting values it's giving me `500` error

Comment: add define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); to your wp-config.php file, so it gives you a more specific error message. as per https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG That should help a lot.